# Why gprof underestimates total time

Tags: profiling, gprof

I have CPU bound process which runs for 5 hours (CPU time by using `getrusage()`)

I tried to profile it by gprof. The total time `main()` took is only about 5000s.

My program is CPU bound, it has some disc IO but it is not that significant. Profile interrupts are on, and my process in not multithreaded.

Answer (score 2):

It only samples in routines it knows about. You calling `new`? That's going to spend time in places where `gprof` doesn't go.

BTW, if you're looking for ways to save some time (after 5 hours I would be) *[you can do better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343)*.