# Discrepancy between gprof and (unix) time; gprof reports lower runtimes

Tags: c++, g++, profiling, profiler, gprof

I have simple sorting program, which I am profiling in order to have a case to study gprof; I later plan to profile a much larger algorithm.

I have compiled with `-pg` and ran ./sort to produce the `gmon.out` file. 
However, when I run `gprof ./sort gmon.out` the values produced in cumulative seconds and self seconds are, as I believe, not accurate.

Firstly, running `time(./sort)` I get:

```
real    0m14.352s
user    0m14.330s
sys     0m0.005s
```

Which is accurate with my stopwatch.

However, the gprof results for the flat profile are:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
%   cumulative   self              self     total           
time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name    
56.18      2.76     2.76        1     2.76     4.71  sort(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)
35.01      4.49     1.72 1870365596     0.00     0.00  std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::operator[](unsigned long)
8.96      4.93     0.44   100071     0.00     0.00  std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::size() const
0.00      4.93     0.00    50001     0.00     0.00  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::construct(int*, int const&)
0.00      4.93     0.00    50001     0.00     0.00  void __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::construct<int>(std::allocator<int>&, int*, int const&)
0.00      4.93     0.00    50001     0.00     0.00  std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&)
0.00      4.93     0.00    50001     0.00     0.00  operator new(unsigned long, void*)
0.00      4.93     0.00      170     0.00     0.00  std::_Iter_base<int*, false>::_S_base(int*)
0.00      4.93     0.00      102     0.00     0.00  std::_Niter_base<int*>::iterator_type std::__niter_base<int*>(int*)
0.00      4.93     0.00       68     0.00     0.00  __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::base() const
0.00      4.93     0.00       68     0.00     0.00  std::_Miter_base<int*>::iterator_type std::__miter_base<int*>(int*)
0.00      4.93     0.00       52     0.00     0.00  std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_get_Tp_allocator()
0.00      4.93     0.00       51     0.00     0.00  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::max_size() const
0.00      4.93     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<int> >::max_size(std::allocator<int> const&)
0.00      4.93     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::__normal_iterator(int* const&)
0.00      4.93     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_get_Tp_allocator() const
0.00      4.93     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::max_size() const
0.00      4.93     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  int* std::__copy_move<false, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m<int>(int const*, int const*, int*)
0.00      4.93     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  int* std::__uninitialized_copy<true>::__uninit_copy<int*, int*>(int*, int*, int*)
0.00      4.93     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  int* std::__copy_move_a<false, int*, int*>(int*, int*, int*)
0.00      4.93     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  int* std::__copy_move_a2<false, int*, int*>(int*, int*, int*)
0.00      4.93     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  int* std::uninitialized_copy<int*, int*>(int*, int*, int*)
0.00      4.93     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  int* std::__uninitialized_copy_a<int*, int*, int>(int*, int*, int*, std::allocator<int>&)
0.00      4.93     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  int* std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a<int*, int*, std::allocator<int> >(int*, int*, int*, std::allocator<int>&)
0.00      4.93     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  int* std::copy<int*, int*>(int*, int*, int*)
0.00      4.93     0.00       18     0.00     0.00  void std::_Destroy_aux<true>::__destroy<int*>(int*, int*)
0.00      4.93     0.00       18     0.00     0.00  std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_deallocate(int*, unsigned long)
0.00      4.93     0.00       18     0.00     0.00  void std::_Destroy<int*>(int*, int*)
0.00      4.93     0.00       18     0.00     0.00  void std::_Destroy<int*, int>(int*, int*, std::allocator<int>&)
0.00      4.93     0.00       17     0.00     0.00  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long)
0.00      4.93     0.00       17     0.00     0.00  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)
0.00      4.93     0.00       17     0.00     0.00  __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >::difference_type __gnu_cxx::operator-<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&)
0.00      4.93     0.00       17     0.00     0.00  std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_check_len(unsigned long, char const*) const
0.00      4.93     0.00       17     0.00     0.00  std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long)
0.00      4.93     0.00       17     0.00     0.00  std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&)
0.00      4.93     0.00       17     0.00     0.00  std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::end()
0.00      4.93     0.00       17     0.00     0.00  std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::begin()
0.00      4.93     0.00       17     0.00     0.00  unsigned long const& std::max<unsigned long>(unsigned long const&, unsigned long const&)
0.00      4.93     0.00        2     0.00     0.00  std::operator|(std::_Ios_Openmode, std::_Ios_Openmode)
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  generateData(std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.22  writeSortedFile(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  loadBuf(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::new_allocator()
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::~new_allocator()
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  std::allocator<int>::allocator()
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  std::allocator<int>::~allocator()
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl::_Vector_impl()
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl::~_Vector_impl()
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_base()
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::~_Vector_base()
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector()
0.00      4.93     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector()
```

So, the cumulative seconds do not accumulate to the true value (~14s), it would appear. The results do show that `sort()` is the most time costly, but the actual time values do not add up. 
`-z` does not change this, but thats expected. 
The call graph (not included), does not seem to show anything that suggests where the missing seconds are; i.e the extra seconds are not in children.

I seem to get similar results (where gprof gives much smaller time values than expected) when I try and profile my larger algorithm which I mention above - gprof says the runtime is ~450s, where as it actually takes over 3hrs. I though this was due to gprof not being able to handle MPI, which the larger algorithm uses extensively, but now I think I am either misinterpreting the gprof results, or I am missing some flags.

Is it possible I am not actually taking into account my `gmon.out` file?
The reason I think this is that, when I run `gprof ./sort` I get the exact same results as `gprof ./sort gmon.out`. Therefore, it seems like its not even using `gmon.out`.  I thought `gmon.out` was needed in conjunction with the executable to map time to functions. How can gprof produce an output without `gmon.out`?

Any enlightening information is more than welcome, thanks in advance!

NOTE:
reading around e.g ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746167/why-gprof-underestimates-total-time?rq=1)) , I found info suggesting that gprof has trouble with analysis heap allocation etc (`new`). I should note that `./sort` uses `std::vector` to hold elements, which will be allocated to heap. Please let me know if this is a possible issue.

Comment: Studying gprof? I've got some reading for you: [*this,*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771) [*this,*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25870103/23771) and [*this,*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27867426/23771) for starters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gprof` doesn't know about functions it doesn't have debug info access to, i.e the standard library. If you want to get accurate elapsed time and still get a callgraph you can use `perf`.

As an example I wrote a program that loops 10000 times. In this loop, I fill a vector with random values and then sort it. For `gprof`, I do the following steps:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -pg -g
./a.out
gprof -b ./a.out
```

`gmon.out` is created if it doesn't exist, and overwritten if it does, and is automatically used by `gprof` if you don't specify a file to use. `-b` suppresses the text blurbs.

Here's example output:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name    
100.52      4.94     4.94                             frame_dummy
  0.00      4.94     0.00       26     0.00     0.00  void std::__adjust_heap<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, long, double, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, long, long, double, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter)
  0.00      4.94     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
```

As you can see, it only records the time for the vector heap implementation, and doesn't know about sort (or anything else) at all. Now let's try `perf`:

```
perf record -g ./a.out
perf report --call-graph --stdio

# Total Lost Samples: 0
#
# Samples: 32K of event 'cycles'
# Event count (approx.): 31899806183
#
# Children      Self  Command  Shared Object        Symbol                                                                            
# ........  ........  .......  ...................  ..................................................................................
#
    99.98%    34.46%  a.out    a.out                [.] main                                                                          
              |          
              |--65.52%-- main
              |          |          
              |          |--65.29%-- std::__introsort_loop<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double
```

*[Rest of text omitted]*

As you can see, `perf` catches the sort function. If I ran `perf stat`, I would also get the accurate runtime.

If you're using GCC, you can pass `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` to have it use the debug library implementation. This will make your code run a lot slower, but necessary in order for `gprof` to see those functions. An example:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 test.cpp -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -pg -g
./a.out
gprof -b ./a.out

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  us/call  us/call  name    
 88.26      0.15     0.15   102875     1.46     1.46  __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > > std::__unguarded_partition<__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter>(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter)
 11.77      0.17     0.02   996280     0.02     0.02  void std::__unguarded_linear_insert<__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_less_iter>(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Val_less_iter)
  0.00      0.17     0.00   417220     0.00     0.00  frame_dummy
  0.00      0.17     0.00   102875     0.00     0.00  void std::__move_median_to_first<__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter>(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter)
  0.00      0.17     0.00     1000     0.00     0.25  void std::__insertion_sort<__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter>(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::__cxx1998::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, std::__debug::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >, __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter)
  0.00      0.17     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
```

I deliberately reduced the amount of iterations to make the execution complete in a reasonable amount of time, but you see `gprof` now shows the functions it wasn't counting before.

Comment: So perf has access to the stl? I am currently running perf as we speak, as it seems to be giving correct results with ./sort